# JSONValue doesn't parse the JSON response

Tags: ios, json

when i try to parse the response returned from a web service i got this stack:

```
JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x6e76c30 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"
)
```

My code is like this:

```
if(request.responseStatusCode==200)
    {   
        NSLog(@"so far, this block of code works");//this log is displayed
        //parse the response
        NSArray *array=[[request responseString]JSONValue];
               //processing the array and do whatever
```

In this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/json-framework/browse_thread/thread/fa32e6aa00be9ff7?pli=1) they talking about an old version of the JSON library and how to update it, please help me figure out what should i do.

**EDIT:**

when trying to parse the response, i wanted to see why the server return, so an `NSLog` like so:

```
if(request.responseStatusCode==200)
        {   
               NSLog(@"the request is %@", request.responseString);
            //parse the response
            NSArray *array=[[request responseString]JSONValue];
                   //processing the array and do whatever
```

give me this stack:

```
the request is <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed in <b>/homepages/25/xxxx/htdocs/my app/webservices/index.php</b> on line <b>39</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function sendResponse() in <b>/homepages/25/xxxxx/htdocs/my app/webservices/index.php</b> on line <b>57</b><br />
2012-01-20 15:10:45.491 my-iPhone-application[882:11603] -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x6ebd450 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"
)
```

**EDIT 2:**

My application sent an array that is supposed to be received and processed in the web services. So one example of how the array received looks like is:

```
(
    Mairie,
    \"Pr\\U00e9fectures et sous-pr\\U00e9fectures\",
    \"Auto-\\U00e9cole\"
)
```

The strange ant-slashes and 00 are the `é` caracter. Am i wrong to use them in my data? Is this which is causing my problem?

Comment: Maybe it's not valid JSON? Edit your question and add the server response you are trying to parse.

Comment: the server response - something like the output of `NSLog(@"%@", [request responseString]);`

Comment: Maybe the server is sending you an empty string - what do you see if you go to the same URL in a browser (or with curl on a command line etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error pretty much says it all, the parser does not consider the JSON string is it reading to be valid JSON. "Unrecognised leading character" means that it found something other than a `{` or `[` character as the first character in the string returned from `[request responseString]`

If you post the raw JSON we might be able to help you point out exactly what is wrong with the response.

HTH

Comment: Hello Devunwired, i have displayed the response returned by the server to see what it gives, please have a look at my edited post above, thanx in advance :)

Comment: So, the server sent you back the string `<br />`, which is HTML (and incomplete at that) and not a valid JSON string, so it sounds like you need to check that you are making the right request and that the web service is functioning correctly.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post, the data are well received from the application in my webservices side, however, i have doubt in `é` caracters. How can i solve this please?

Answer (score 1):

If `request.responseString` returns `<br />` then it looks like your server is returning HTML and HTML isn't JSON ;)

Your use of the JSON library is correct, it's either your request or (more likely given the response) your server thats broken.

On the plus side, you have accidentally done some error testing on your app :)

Comment: I have edited my post, i got another stack when i try to display the response string, please have a look, may be you can help me there :)

Comment: Hi, what you mean exactly by `accidentally done some error testing on your app` please, btw, i just tested my web service on the navigator, the php side is working great

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post, the server is sending me a valid array (see my post) but in contains 'é' caracters in which i have doubt that are causing problems, please correct me if i am wrong. Thanx

Comment: That's not JSON. Not even slightly.